# How to implement 3D model in web(locally) and interaction is based in the datas in database?

Tags: html, phpmyadmin, 3dsmax

I want to create a hotel in 3D and emebed it to HTML. The interaction will be rotatetable vertically and windows of the room will be clickable and color of the window(changes like there is light inside the room on and off) and the most crucial for me is the interaction is base on the database. So if in the database room 1 is available. So in HTML where I embed the 3D model of the hotel  room 1 will be lights on and clickable. Is it possible? What are the tools? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. But essentially you are loooking for a way to render realtime 3d content in the browser. 
Game engines like [Unity 3D](https://unity3d.com/) can do this and can even compile your 3d models to web gl format which runs natively in a browser. It is also possible to build in interactivity that you are looking for.

There are also a number of HTML5 libraries but might not offer ability to load 3ds max models out of the box.